# MobileFirst Quality Assurance - Setting up on-premise MQA

Tags: mobilefirst-qa

I am trying to set up on-premise MQA but encountered a few problems.

I have tried MQA 6.3, 7.0, as well as Bluemix MQA service for comparison but on-premise MQA is what we eventually need.

1. For MQA 6.3, I am able to get most of the functionality working except the js crash reports. The problem is I can see the "crash" entry in each individual session details but not on the dashboard like Android crash report triggered by java exception. 
   I am not sure if it's my setting's problem or not. If this is the intended behavior, then it's very hard to track the js errors since no one will be able to click through all the session details. 
   I have tried it on Bluemix MQA which shows the js crash error on dashboard correctly.
2. For MQA 7.0, I got the web UI up and running ok. However, when I tried to upload an apk/ipa, I get SSL error. From browser debug and apphance log, I see https://my_ip/api/v1/resources/installer/store/ is causing the problem. 

   Is it possible to run MQA 7.0 without SSL for internal development server that has only ip?
    I tried to set the following settings in local_settings.py but get the same error.

   SSLIFY_DISABLE = True
   CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
   SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False

Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you mean by:

> I have tried it on Bluemix MQA which shows the js crash error on dashboard correctly.

How are you seeing the crashes displaying differently in Bluemix than for on-prem?

Unfortunately its not possible to run MQA 7.0 without SSL.

Comment: From application's dashboard, there is "Latest Feedback", "Latest Bugs", and "Latest Crashes". JS errors are displayed under "Latest Crashes". Also there is red exclamation mark next to the session which the js error happens. For MQA 6.3, no js error is shown under "Latest Crashes" and not even the red exclamation mark is shown next to the session list. However, I do see the crash detail listed when in click into the session details.